# How to control cdrom motor speed from the command line?

Tags: c, performance, drive, ioctl, cd

I would like to be able to control the cdrom drive speed from the command line, either with or without a CD in the drive. I don't expect there are any existing command line utilities to do this, but perhaps it's possible to write a C programme to do this using the IOCTL functions?

So does anyone know if this is first of all possible? And secondly, would this be the way to approach it?

I assume the CDROM_SELECT_SPEED function is the write speed? ie 8x, 16x etc.

Perhaps I could just make a command to spin-up the drive without a CD in it?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: A quick googling brought up this (untested): http://dmpc.dbp.fmph.uniba.sk/~krivanek/cdrom_speed/

Comment: I like the question, but why would you ever spin up the drive without a CD in it?

Comment: I would like to to do something along the lines of this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHJOz_y9rZE but with the cd drive still in the machine. Even just making it spin on command might be suffcient..